# How do I extract the text from a docx file using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, docx

The files are saved in a Drive folder. I need to send the text content of all .docx file as an API payload. I've tried using `Blob` but to no avail. Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Did your issue get solved?

Comment: Yeah, your solution did it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send the text content of a docx file that you have in Drive. If that's correct, then you can do the following:

```
function docx() {
  var docxId ="your-docx-id";
  var docx = DriveApp.getFileById(docxId);
  var blob = docx.getBlob();
  var file = Drive.Files.insert({}, blob, {convert:true});
  var id = file["id"];
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
  var text = doc.getBody().getText();
  return text;
}
```

This code uses [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to create a Docs file out of the `blob` you get from the `docx`, via [Drive.Files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert). Then, you can easily access this newly created file via DocumentApp and use [getText](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert).

Bear in mind that this will create a new file every time you run it. Use [Files.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete) to avoid that.

I hope this is of any help.